# Point density from XY table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, amazon-web-services

I have a large 1.1gb CSV table of points in Lat/Long WGS84 for which I'd like to generate a point density raster. I'm taking the following steps but the process is extremely slow. I welcome any advice on how to improve this or better understand where exactly my bottlenecks are.

In ModelBuilder I have the following steps

1. XY Table to Points - output to in_memory workspace;
2. Project - reproject in_memory output from LatLong WGS84 to WGS84 Web
   Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) - here I'm unable to store the output
   in_memory (not sure why) so I write it to the gdb;
3. Point Density - calculate my point density raster from the output of
   2.

I'm running on Windows Server 2019 with Intel Xeon Platinum 8175M CPU @2.5GHz (2 processors), 760GB RAM, 64-bit OS which I've spun up an AWS instance with 500GB hard disk.

Currently my ModelBuilder is on step 1 at 1% and it has been there for a while. My CPU usage is at 1% and Memory also at 1%

How can I speed up my process?

Comment: Try writing your CSV to a file geodatabase instead of in_memory?

Comment: How long does each step take if run manually using the same tool and parameter values in the Geoprocessing pane?

Comment: @PolyGeo Not sure what you mean by manually. I built my model and saved it and then hit run from the geoprocessing window. it took 4h15m to run step 1, 1h15m for step 2, and 15min for step 3.

Comment: @Hornbydd if I write to the gdb it takes just as long or longer.

Comment: the bottleneck is clearly in writing the data from csv into ArcGIS but I'm not sure how to improve on this. I would have hoped that step 2 could be a little faster too.

Comment: Running manually means not using ModelBuilder while you learn more about how each tool performs by testing them individually.  If the first step is your biggest concern then I think you should focus this question on that.  If your second step is also of concern then you could start a second question to focus on that.  To reduce the time of your testing cycles I think you should switch your testing over to a subset of your data.

Comment: How many points are being created from the CSV file?

Comment: I'd import CSV to access and split it in chunks. Convert, project each part and merge. 1 gb text file is too big.

Comment: @Hornbydd around 60 million points in each csv.... and used to create the point density map